# Qual arquivo no tema wordpress que seta o idioma a ser utilizado?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Eu criei um arquivo .pot e .mo com uma tradução de um tema para o português do Brasil, portanto essa atualização não esta sendo aplicada, ele ainda continua carregando as strings no idioma original. Alguém sabe qual o arquivo responsável por setar/definir o arquivo de idioma que será usado? Procurei na internet mais não achei a resposta que estou procurando!

Comment: Se o seu tema está bem configurado apenas as configurações no painel de administração deve fazer essa alteração automaticamente.

Comment: @AtilaSilva acho que isso não ta acontecendo cara, por isso queria setar manualmente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salve, WPFan! Tudo bem?

Cara, eu costumo fazer as traduções usando um arquivo .mo e um .po, gerados pelo [Poedit](https://poedit.net/) (Normalmente edito o arquivo .po na mão, importo no poedit e exporto o .mo gerado e coloco na pasta de tradução dos temas). Os arquivos vão para `wp-content/languages/themes` e eu uso a nomenclatura como `nomedotema-en_US.po` e `nomedotema-en_US.mo`, onde **en_US** é o código do idioma.

Comment: tbm faço mais ou menos isso, eu até tenho a versão premium do Poedit, que utilizo também para as minhas aplicações em asp net mvc. Mas, eu descobri a causa do problema, existia um outro arquivo gerado pelo template ativado, tive apenas que desativa-lo, dai o meu .mo e .po funcionou corretamente. No mais obrigado!